# How to detect "suggests text" is turned on for current keyboard in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In Windows Phone, when the keyboard is up, there's usually a "suggestion line" above the keys.

For some languagea, this suggestion line is always there, such as eastern Asian languages.
For some other languages, like English, I can turn this off by going to "Settings" -> "Keyboard" -> "English" and uncheck "Suggest text".
And there are some languages that don't have suggestion line at all.

My questions is, how do I detect whether current keyboard has the suggestion line enabled or not?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot check that information through any API. In windows phone some API are not visible to developers. In your case also suggestion text information API is not accessible to developers for development.